# Directed search in Cypher and Neo4j Bloom

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given the following model:

```
Nodes: Host, Listener
Relations: Host -HOSTS-> Listener, Listener -CONNECTS_TO-> Listener
```

I want to perform a directed search on the CONNECTS_TO relation, to see the paths from host A to host B, but only if exists a listener on A that connects to a listener on B. Something like this:

`(A:Host)-[:HOSTS]-(L_A:Listener)-[:CONNECTS_TO]->(L_B:Listener)-[:HOSTS]-(B:Host)`

So for instance if I do have a relation L_A -CONNECTS_TO-> L_B, the query should return the path A->L_A->L_B<-B,
but if I also have a relation L_B-CONNECTS_TO->L_A the query should still return only the first path, since I'm looking for path from A to B, and if my only relation is the second one, the query should not return anything since A cannot connect to B, only B to A.

My Cypher query looks something like this, but still all the relations are returned:

```
match path=(A:Host)-[:HOSTS]-(L_A:Listener)-[:CONNECTS_TO*1]->(L_B:Listener)-[:HOSTS]-(B:Host) 
where A.name = 'hostA' and B.name = 'hostB'
return path;
```

but Neo4j Browser still returns all the paths between A and B regardless of the CONNECTS_TO's direction. I also try to perform the same directed query in Bloom, but to no avail, so my questions are:

1. What might be wrong with my Cypher query?
2. Is it possible to perform this directed search in Bloom (as I cannot seem to see any directions there)?

Thank you!

LE: graph generation

```
create 
(_0:`Host`  {`name`:"hostA"}),
(_1:`Host`  {`name`:"hostB"}),
(_2:`Host`  {`name`:"hostC"}),
(_3:`Listener`  {`name`:"listenerA"}),
(_4:`Listener`  {`name`:"listenerB"}),
(_5:`Listener`  {`name`:"listenerC"}),
(_0)-[:`HOSTS`]->(_3),
(_1)-[:`HOSTS`]->(_4),
(_2)-[:`HOSTS`]->(_5),
(_3)-[:`CONNECTS_TO`]->(_5),
(_3)-[:`CONNECTS_TO`]->(_4),
(_4)-[:`CONNECTS_TO`]->(_3),
(_5)-[:`CONNECTS_TO`]->(_4)
```

query for my only direct path between A and B:

```
match path=(source:Host)-[:HOSTS]-(l_source:Listener)-[:CONNECTS_TO*1]->(l_dest:Listener)-[:HOSTS]-(dest:Host) where source.name = 'hostA' and dest.name = 'hostB' return path;
```

https://console.neo4j.org/ here, it seems to work just fine, and at a closer look the json/text/table result in Neo4j Browser also seems correct, it's just that the visualization shows all the relations regardless of direction. Is there a way to display only the ones that I'm interested in? I know they can be interpreted as bi-directional, but in this case the direction it's quite important.

In Bloom, even though the search path is correct, and the number of nodes found is also correct, in this case 4 (hostA, listenerA, listenerB, hostB), all the nodes and relations are displayed, and this is what I'm trying to avoid, as our structure is very big, and we want to visualize certain paths only.
[image]

Comment: please give us sample data so that we can see and test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's just that the visualization shows all the relations regardless of direction. Is there a way to display only the ones that I'm interested in?

If it is just the visualization, did you turn off the *Connect result nodes* feature in the browser?

[image: connect result nodes check box]

With the option turned on I get:

[image: check box toggled on]

Turned off:

[image: check box toggled off]

For Bloom one option would be to put the query into a search phrase like this:

[image: search phrase bloom]

The resulting visualization will only show the query matching relationships:

[image: bloom]

Comment: first of all, thank you for your answer. as you can see in your image, even though "hostC" is not involved at all in the result, it is still displayed in the perspective. in this particular example it doesn't seem to be an issue, but as the topology increases, it kinda is, and we try to avoid any extra nodes/relations when we query the paths. perhaps it's not possible to do this in Bloom? i.e. display only hostA, hostB and the path and hide everything else? thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, this was something I have overseen when taking the screenshot. The scene had already all nodes in there before issuing the phrase. It has to get invoked on an empty scene. Will change the screenshot.

Comment: yes, I can confirm this, the scene must be fully cleared first and it works. you really helped me shed light on this. thanks!